# Docker swarm unresponsive after scaling VMSS in Azure

Tags: azure, docker

I've got a web app running on a Docker swarm in Azure that was set up through the Docker EE For Azure (17.06) bootstrapper.  As the website isn't currently processing a large amount of traffic, I scaled the VM size down to the cheapest option (A0).  After scaling these down website was unresponsive.

I SSHed on to a manager node and typing commands was slow.  Figuring that I'd scaled down too much I scaled back up to the previous tier I had been on (D1_v2).

My website remained unresponsive so I SSHed onto a manager again.  The terminal was responsive, however docker commands such as `docker service ls` and `docker node ls` do nothing.  The VM in general seems to be working fine, however.  I can  `cat` files, run `docker version` etc.

Does anyone have any ideas why this may have happened?  Is there any way I can fix it, or is my best option to just provision a new environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Azure Support to see if they could provide any further assistance with this.  They advised scaling the number of VMs in my Scale Set which I couldn't do because we had reached our allocated limit in that zone.

Azure were unable to provide any information as to how this may have happened and recommended provisioning a new environment as the best solution.